# Webstorm ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Illegal Constraint: 'ins 0 ??px 0 0'

Tags: webstorm

In WebStorm 2019.3.2, when I using push option (`Ctrl+Shift+k`) to push my commits, it does not work and no error message shown in the IDE. I found the error message below from the IDE's log file.

It worths to mention that all the other git options (pull, fetch, etc.) work fine. also, I'm able to push the commits using git bash or even using source tree application. so I don't think there is a problem with git itself.

Does anyone face this problem and have any solution?

```
2020-02-05 08:39:00,676 [143412984]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Illegal Constraint: 'ins 0 ??px 0 0'
Malformed UnitValue: '??px' 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal Constraint: 'ins 0 ??px 0 0'
Malformed UnitValue: '??px'
    at net.miginfocom.layout.ConstraintParser.parseLayoutConstraint(Unknown Source)
    at net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout.setLayoutConstraints(Unknown Source)
    at net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.dvcs.push.ui.VcsPushDialog.createSouthOptionsPanel(VcsPushDialog.java:136)
    at com.intellij.dvcs.push.ui.VcsPushDialog.createSouthAdditionalPanel(VcsPushDialog.java:97)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.createSouthPanel(DialogWrapper.java:651)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.createSouthPanel(DialogWrapper.java:536)
    at com.intellij.dvcs.push.ui.VcsPushDialog.createSouthPanel(VcsPushDialog.java:102)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.init(DialogWrapper.java:1345)
    at com.intellij.dvcs.push.ui.VcsPushDialog.<init>(VcsPushDialog.java:81)
    at com.intellij.dvcs.push.ui.VcsPushDialog.<init>(VcsPushDialog.java:61)
    at com.intellij.dvcs.push.VcsPushAction.actionPerformed(VcsPushAction.java:32)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:298)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:294)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:263)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:77)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:284)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:83)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:107)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:121)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:517)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:36)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:539)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6651)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6416)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5026)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4858)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4858)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:908)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:846)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:778)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
2020-02-05 08:39:00,677 [143412985]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - WebStorm 2019.3.2  Build #WS-193.6015.40 
2020-02-05 08:39:00,677 [143412985]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.5; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2020-02-05 08:39:00,677 [143412985]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Windows 10 
2020-02-05 08:39:00,677 [143412985]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action: Vcs.Push
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issue, [IDEA-231545](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-231545) is fixed in the next major release (2020.1)

Comment: are you sure it's related to my problem? the issue title is `Push Dialog cannot be opened with Hindi locale`, which is I'm not using Hindi locale at all.